# Create a main method in a Jersey web application

Tags: java, maven, jersey, program-entry-point

I have created a web application using Jersey and Maven, and I want to execute some code when the server starts, not when a function is called.

```
@Path("/Users") 
public class User {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {    
            System.out.println("Main executed");
           //I want to execute some code here
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/prof") 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> getFile(@QueryParam("userid") String userid, {
```

But the `main` method is never executed, I never see the output `Main executed`.
I have also tried to create a new class with a normal `main` method, but it also never executes.

Comment: in server apps the execution/class loading is not the same as console/desktop apps, in web apps, you can use ApplicationListener which have several events, what you may care about is creating a class that implements `ServletContextListener` and declare it in your web.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) implementation, and register it in your `web.xml` file:

`ApplicationServletContextListener.java`:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ApplicationServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Application started");  
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      com.yourapp.ApplicationServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

If using servlet 3.0, you can also just annotate the class with the [`@WebListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation instead of registering it in your `web.xml` file.

---

Alternatively, as another user points out, Jersey includes an [`ApplicationEventListener`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEventListener.html) that you can use to perform an action once the application is initialized:

`MyApplicationEventListener.java`:

```
public class MyApplicationEventListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

    private volatile int requestCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        switch (event.getType()) {
            case INITIALIZATION_FINISHED:
                System.out.println("Application was initialized.");
                break;
            case DESTROY_FINISHED:
                System.out.println("Application was destroyed.");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        requestCount++;
        System.out.println("Request " + requestCount + " started.");

        // return the listener instance that will handle this request.
        return new MyRequestEventListener(requestCnt);
    }
}
```

Note that this is not part of the JAX-RS standard, and will tie your application to using Jersey.